# How to get first integer value which is equal or more than number?

Tags: c++, integer

Helow :)

I have to find **first integer value** which should be greater or equal to the chosen **number**...

for example I have  a

```
include<math.h>
number=sqrt(26);
```

which is : **5.09902....**  so a program must print a number which
is more than **5.09902...** and it must print **6**

but if i have number=sqrt(25);
program must print  **5**

can someone post a little source how to do it ? :))
Thanks...

Comment: 5.09902 should print 6? Or is it the normal <5.5 prints 5 and >5.5 prints 6?

Answer (score 11):

Try the `ceil`-function:

```
number=ceil(sqrt(26));
```

Also, when programming C++, don't use `math.h`, instead use `cmath`. `cmath` puts all functions into the `std`-namespace, and thus does not polute the global namespace. Your could would look like this then:

```
#include <cmath>

// ...

number = std::ceil(std::sqrt(26));
```

Using namespaces is important. You should get comfortable with it.

Comment: While C++98 demands it, the use of `<cmath>` instead of `<math.h>` doesn't guarantee in practice that the names are not introduced in the global namespace. And the reasons are important enough that C++0X standardized the practice and doesn't demand that anymore.

Comment: @AProgrammer: Do I understand that right - function in C-headers are no longer in the `std`-namespace in C++0x?

Comment: C++03: <cmath> only in std, <math.h> in global, perhaps in std. C++0X: <cmath> in std, perhaps in global, <math.h> in global, perhaps in std.